# Telethon | client.get_participants('test')

Tags: python, filter, printing, telethon

```
import telethon
import sys

api_id = 
api_hash = ''


client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()


me = client.get_me()
print(me)

parti = client.get_participants('')
len(parti)
type(parti)



for x in parti:
   print(x)
```

Type of parti: 'telethon.helpers.TotalList'
Length of parti is correct, so it indeed scraped the correct users.
But when it comes to printing, it prints:

```
User(id=xxxxxxx, is_self=False, contact=False, mutual_contact=False, deleted=False, bot=False, bot_chat_history=False, bot_nochats=False, verified=False, restricted=False, min=False, bot_inline_geo=False, access_hash=3186925291802818105, first_name='vakuumtaucher', last_name=None, username=None, phone=None, photo=UserProfilePhoto(photo_id=2834571071698610090, photo_small=FileLocation(dc_id=2, volume_id=250821725, local_id=227886, secret=-1295815918865284037), photo_big=FileLocation(dc_id=2, volume_id=250821725, local_id=227888, secret=2864116761608555039)), status=UserStatusRecently(), bot_info_version=None, restriction_reason=None, bot_inline_placeholder=None, lang_code=None)
User(id=553795975, is_self=False, contact=False, mutual_contact=False, deleted=False, bot=False, bot_chat_history=False, bot_nochats=False, verified=False, restricted=False, min=False, bot_inline_geo=False, access_hash=3748681057114558961, first_name='René', last_name=None, username='Todtnauer', phone=None, photo=UserProfilePhoto(photo_id=2378535601737672619, photo_small=FileLocation(dc_id=2, volume_id=246934435, local_id=108141, secret=-2834728750137465782), photo_big=FileLocation(dc_id=2, volume_id=246934435, local_id=108143, secret=-7220306442079900232)), status=UserStatusOffline(was_online=datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 24, 10, 38, 31, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)), bot_info_version=None, restriction_reason=None, bot_inline_placeholder=None, lang_code=None)
```

That works fine, till a user with Non-BMP characters pop ups, because then I get an UnicodeEncodeError.

How can I just filter the user_id out of the printed user? (to bypass the UnicodeEncodeError)?

Comment: So if I asked the question unclearly:

I wanted to know how to just print the User(id=xxxx, ...) part, so I just need the ID, and that should also filter the problem of the UnicodeEncodeError

Comment: The UnicodeEncodeError is an issue with your terminal and has already been answered plenty of times before.

Answer (score 2):

`User` is an object and to access an object property you have to do `object.property` so in your case you have to do the following.

```
for x in parti:
   print(x.id)
```